# Determine the equation(s) of the lines that are tangent to $y = x^2 + 3x + 1$ and pass through the origin.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, tangent-line

I am trying to solve the question but I am not sure how to approach it. The derivative is 2x+3 but does that have any significance when solving this?

Comment: Hint : try to state the restrictions in formulas, i.e. the formula of a tangent line to a point + the tangent line passes through the origin

Answer (score 4):

Hint: The equation of a line tangent to a function $f(x)$ at point $x=c$ is

$$y-f(c)=f'(c)(x-c).$$

Determine all $c$ such that the line contains the origin:

$$f(c)=f'(c)c.$$

Comment: Sorry but I am taking calc course for the first time. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @confusedcalcstudent which part is unclear?

Comment: I don't understand the equation. How do I plug in the values? How do I find the c value?

Comment: @confusedcalcstudent Which equation don't you understand, first or second?

Comment: second equation

Comment: You are given the function $f$ i.e. the parabola. You already computed $f'$. Now solve $f(c)=f'(c)c$. The solutions are all points $c$ where the tangent line of $f$ at $x=c$ contains the origin

Comment: @confusedcalcstudent The equation of the tangent line can be rewritten as
$$ y = f'(c) x + (f(c)-c f'(c)),$$
and this line will pass through the origin if an only if $f(c)-cf'(c) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

This one is perhaps simpler without calculus: as lines through the origin have form $y=mx$, you are looking for values of $m$ that give exactly one real root for $mx=x^2+3x+1$.  So set the discriminant to zero...

Answer (score 0):

We can easily get the tangent points of interest.
We have

- $f(x)=x^2+3x+1$ as well as
- $f'(x)=2x+3$

We'll define

$g(x)=3x+2$ and set this to equal $f(x)$. So,

$x^2+3x+1=3x+2$ or simply $x^2=1$.

This gives us the x-values of our function $f(x)$ where tangents pass throught $(0,0)$. We get $x_1=-1$ and $x_2=1$, so we have the tangent points in $f(-1)$ and $f(1)$ being $t_1=(-1,-1)$ and $t_2=(1,5)$.

Thus, the two tangents are of form

$t: y_1=x$ and $t: y_2=5x$.

Comment: Why did you define $g(x)$ as $3x + 2$?  Why did you set $g(x) = f(x)$?